# How do I convert a normal string and use "n0" text formatting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using unity 2d so `CalcNumbers` is a text variable and `SecondNumbers` is a string variable, Also sorry if I am bad at asking this question I am new to C#

```
CalcNumbers.text = SecondNumbers.ToString("n0");
```

So I tried this but I always end up getting an error do you guys have any help.

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: I am making a calculator

Comment: If `SecondNumbers` already **is** a `string` then what exactly are you trying to achieve here? What is `string.ToString("n0")` supposed to return in your opinion?

Comment: please add the error to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that you need a number, not a string to convert to string.
You are converting a string to another string.
YOu need parse the string first to a int or float.
Then make the ToString("n0");

Example:

```
private void FormateText()
{
    CalcNumbers.text = float.Parse(SecondNumbers).ToString("n0");
}
```